# What does this Firefox symbol mean?

Tags: firefox, anchor

This symbol of a ripped paper is appearing on some of my `<a>` tags in Firefox Browser..

Here is an example:

[image: example]

Does anyone know what this means?

Thanks!!

**update** : here's some code:

```
<a href="#"  onClick="jQuery('#youtube-player-container').tubeplayer('play');">
<img class="mp3button" style="background-image:url('/mp3_play.png');background-size:100% 100%;" />
</a>
```

(the image does appear appears so it's not a problem with the img src)

Comment: What firefox add-ons do you have? Perhaps this is from an add-on.

Comment: i don't think so, no add-ons are enabled right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ripped paper icon is for a broken image src.  You would see it if you requested an image that didn't exists ie:

```
<img src="notarealimage.jpg"/>
```

In your case you have no src attribute, which is why the browser sees it as a broken image.
Given that you're using a background image on your img tag, I suggest changing the img tag to a span or div tag, or just adding the style attribute to the a tag and removing the img tag altogether, i.e:

```
<a href="#"  onClick="jQuery('#youtube-player-container').tubeplayer('play');" class="mp3button" style="background-image:url('/mp3_play.png');background-size:100% 100%;"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! The only reason I'm using an img tag is because the style i wanted didn't work on the `<a>` tag. I'll be switching it to a non `<img>` tag now. Thanks for the response